# How to grant discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID permission?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

To retrieve actual logged in iCloud user's info via CloudKit, I need to call the `discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID` method.

Its API says:

> The user must have granted the
>   CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability permission for this
>   container.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase
defaultContainer.requestApplicationPermission(.PermissionUserDiscoverability, {status, error in 

})
```

Requests the specified permission from the user asynchronously.

The first time you request a permission on any of the user’s devices, the user is prompted to grant or deny the request. Once the user grants or denies a permission, subsequent requests for the same permission (on the same or separate devices) do not prompt the user again.
This method runs asynchronously and delivers the results to the block you provide.

Comment: Please explain code when posting answers, we are here to help people become better. Give a man a fish...

Comment: Absolutely not, ask any of the long term respected members of SO and I think you will find they disagree with you.

Answer (score 4):

## Swift

```
CKContainer.defaultContainer().requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.PermissionUserDiscoverability, 
                 completionHandler: {
                      applicationPermissionStatus, error in
                           // check (applicationPermissionStatus == CKApplicationPermissionStatus.Granted)
})
```

## Objective-C

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] requestApplicationPermission:CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability
                 completionHandler:^(CKApplicationPermissionStatus applicationPermissionStatus, NSError *error) {
                           // check(applicationPermissionStatus == CKApplicationPermissionStatusGranted)
                 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is updated for Xcode 13 and swift 5:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability) { (status, error) in
/* your code here */
   }
```