# How do I get emailAddress to discoverUserIdentity?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Currently I do:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

        CKContainer.default().discoverUserIdentity(withEmailAddress: "barteks****@icloud.com") { identity, error in

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print(identity)
        }
    }
```

the result is:

> nil
>   nil

I am pretty sure that following address exists, because it is mine. Why it prints nil?

I follow [this](https://medium.com/@kwylez/cloudkit-sharing-series-creating-the-ckshare-40e420b94ee8#.8aubu0cb5) tutorial and got stuck with **Look up via phone** chapter.

**What do I try to do?**

I would like to share some records with other user. But first I need to somehow determine that user. Is it correct?

Comment: Maybe you checked yet but... Is your device/simulator logged on iCloud?

Comment: Because Apple broke this in the iOS 10.3 release. See my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130466/discoverallidentities-discoveruseridentity-returning-nil-for-ckuseridentity-lo

Answer (score 1):

Request permission first:

```
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] requestApplicationPermission:CKApplicationPermissionUserDiscoverability
             completionHandler:^(CKApplicationPermissionStatus applicationPermissionStatus, NSError *error) {
                       // check(applicationPermissionStatus == CKApplicationPermissionStatusGranted)
             });}
```

[How to grant discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595247/how-to-grant-discoveruserinfowithuserrecordid-permission/24622553)